# Why is my regular expression function not working?

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a regular expression function that only gets the words from a string of words and numbers.

```
def get_name(text):
    return re.findall("([\w,'\s]+)",text)[0]
```

But when I execute

```
get_name('Silverbullet201')
```

It still gives me

```
'Silverbullet201.58'
```

I thought my function would only match words, commas, apostrophes, and spaces.

Comment: I doubt that `get_name('JcRadio101.58')` returns `'Silverbullet201.58'`. But anyway, what's the result you *expected*?

Comment: [Sorry, I can't repro](https://ideone.com/OQXu8D). It works as expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce on [regexr](https://regexr.com/3tvdk) either.

Comment: I expected 'Silverbullet'

Comment: You seem to need `re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+', text)` or `re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+(?:[',]\s*[^\W\d_]+)?', text)`, but it is not really clear.

Comment: I think you simply want `[a-zA-Z,' ]+`, after reading `would only match words, commas, apostrophes, and spaces.`

Comment: Did you make up your mind? Is anything working for you?

Answer (score 3):

`\w` includes both alphabets and numbers, as well as underscore, so if your definition of a word is a string of alphabets, then you should simply match with `[A-Za-z]+` instead:

```
def get_name(text):
    return re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+', text)[0]
```

Comment: I also tried return re.findall("([\w,'\s\D]+)",text)[0]

Comment: but that doesn't do anything, shouldn't \D exclude digits?

Comment: `\D` matches anything but digits, but since in the same class you also have `\w`, which includes digits, the class `[\w,'\s\D]` would end up matching all characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting only words (letters) the usage of `\w` is not right which matches also numbers and underscore.

```
def get_name(text):
    return re.findall(r"([A-Za-z]+)",text)[0]
```

is maybe what you wanted.

Comment: same answer. blhsing was faster. :/

Answer (score 0):

`\w` will match letters *and numbers*. You should use `[a-zA-Z]` to include only letters.

```
def get_name(text):
    return re.findall("([a-zA-Z]+)",text)[0]
```

If you still want to match all of the special characters and whitespace, you can use the following:

```
def get_name(text):
    return re.findall("([a-zA-Z,'\s]+)",text)[0]
get_name("Silverbul , 'let' 201.58")
```

Output:

```
"Silverbul , 'let' "
```

Unfortunately you cannot use `[\w\D]` as it will use an `OR` comparison, not an `AND`. In effect you will be saying match if any of the following are true:

1. Any letter, number, or underscore
2. Any non number character

Comment: *and underscores*.